# Набери меня, набрала его вместо позвони мне, позвонила ему

Tags: грамотная-речь

Скажите, пожалуйста, неужели подобные выражения стали нормой? ВО многих  фильмах вместо "позвони" - "набери", причем из уст героев образованных.  А в какой-то группе в соцсетях серьезно обсуждалась правильность "набери меня" или "набери мне". Ни я, ни люди в моем окружении так не говорят.

Comment: Ну, в вашем не говорят, а вообще говорят, и довольно часто. А что тут такого? Язык постоянно меняется, вполне может быть, что скоро это станет допустимым разговорным. А может, и уже стало.

Comment: Судя по вашему комментарию, это выражение не норма даже для разговорного стиля, а только "может быть, станет" ею. Спасибо.

Comment: Может быть, уже и норма. Не смотрел в словарях.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё дело в том, что глагол *набрать* обрёл новое значение: нажать в строго определённом порядке энное количество знаков на клавиатуре какого-либо устройства. *Набери мой номер* в нашем вечном стремлении к краткости речи привело к выражению  *набери меня*.

На мой взгляд, выражение *набери меня* уже стало устойчивым, привычным. Более того, оно, вероятнее всего, останется в языке как фразеологизм, происхождение которого придётся  объяснять уже нашим внукам. Совсем скоро "набирать" ничего и никого не потребуется, так как в современном мире стремительно развиваются новые, более удобные способы коммуникации. Нажал, например, одну кнопочку - и готово, смотри и общайся.

Нравится нам это или нет, но выражение уже широко используется в разговорном стиле.  *В десять вечера позвонил племяннице: набери меня утром.* [Александр Терехов. Каменный мост (1997-2008)] Каюсь, но мой слух это уже не режет.

Comment: Ну хоть и нельзя почему-то говорить спасибо, а я скажу. Спасибо, Екатерина, рада вновь с вами встретиться в рамках форума.